# Getting license to work for imageresizing.net

Tags: imageresizer

in our dev environment I can’t get the license key to work. Please advise.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0ef6b397064ec081db99bd9276fdb59e

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your license key was truncated during copy/paste, as it ends in an ellipsis (...).

Comment: Well that was on purpose :-)

Answer (score 0):

The support team replied - "try iisreset"

And it worked :-)